# Swift: adding SwiftUI element to UIKit project: unable to apply constraints correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui, autolayout, constraints, dropdown

I'm trying to add a drop down element built using SwiftUI to my UIKit project.

I have a custom UIView which contains multiple stack views including this one:

```
internal lazy var valueWithDataUnitStack: UIStackView = {
    
    var stackSubviews = [inputField, dataUnitLabel]
    
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: stackSubviews)
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.spacing = Constants.FontAttributes.valueUnitStackSpacing

    return stack
}()
```

And I have build the following dropdown using SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 14.0.0, *)
struct DataUnitDropDown: View {
    var units = ["ltr", "usg", "impg"]
    
    @State private var selectedDataUnit = 0
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            DisclosureGroup(units[selectedDataUnit], isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< units.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("\(units[index])")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                            .padding(.all)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedDataUnit = index
                                self.isExpanded.toggle()
                            }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a variable called 'isDynamic'. When this is set to 'true' in the init, rather than having

```
[inputField, dataUnitLable]
```

What I would like to have is:

```
[inputField, controller.view]
```

(where controller is the UIHostingController required to inject this SwiftUI element. So I tried the following:

```
internal lazy var valueWithDataUnitStack: UIStackView = {
    
    var stackSubviews = [UIView]()
    if let isDynamic = isDynamicField, isDynamic {
                    stackSubviews = [inputField]
        if #available(iOS 14.0.0, *) {
            let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: DataUnitDropDown())
            controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            controller.view.clipsToBounds = false

            addSubview(controller.view)
            controller.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleLabel.heightAnchor).isActive = true
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
            stackSubviews = [inputField, controller.view]
        }
    } else {
        stackSubviews = [inputField, dataUnitLabel]
    }
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: stackSubviews)
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.spacing = Constants.FontAttributes.valueUnitStackSpacing

    return stack
}()
```

So the idea behind the above is that I need to force the drop down to remain aligned with the other elements at the top. I also need to allow the drop down to expand without affecting the height of the stack it is contained in, hence why I set clipToBounds to false.

However whenever I try to access any of these constraints I'm crashing with:

```
Thread 1: "Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutDimension:0x60000352f880 \"_TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewV10eHandshake16DataUnitDropDown_:0x7fbbdd381960.height\"> and <NSLayoutDimension:0x60000352f8c0 \"UITextField:0x7fbbdb4c33d0.height\"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."
```

How can I inject this element into the stack and make use of existing constraints within the custom UIView class.

NB: There are other UI elements that I could try to use as anchors (e.g. titleLabel which is another UILabel within this custom class). But no matter what element I try to constrain to I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You never added the UIHostingController to the parent ViewController

Usually you would do something like this:

```swift
addChild(controller)
view.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.didMove(toParent: self)
```